# I am having an issue with object-detection and with pycotools.mask

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

Hi I am running a Windows 10 x64 machine running python 3.7 and I am trying to run code off of this [website](https://medium.com/swlh/nvidia-jetson-nano-custom-object-detection-from-scratch-using-tensorflow-and-opencv-113fe4dba134)

It is giving me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "model_main.py", line 25, in <module>
from object_detection import model_lib
File "C:\Python37\models\models-master\research\object_detection\model_lib.py", line 27, in <module>
from object_detection import eval_util
File "C:\Python37\models\models-master\research\object_detection\eval_util.py", line 33, in <module>
from object_detection.metrics import coco_evaluation
File "C:\Python37\models\models-master\research\object_detection\metrics\coco_evaluation.py", line 25, in <module>
from object_detection.metrics import coco_tools
File "C:\Python37\models\models-master\research\object_detection\metrics\coco_tools.py", line 51, in <module>
from pycocotools import coco
File "C:\Python37\models\models-master\research\pycocotools\coco.py", line 55, in <module>
from . import mask as maskUtils
File "C:\Python37\models\models-master\research\pycocotools\mask.py", line 3, in <module>
import pycocotools._mask as _mask
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pycocotools._mask'
```

I have tried to run the `setup.py install` from the cocoapi\PythonAPI directory and get this error

```
running install
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
creating pycocotools.egg-info
writing pycocotools.egg-info\PKG-INFO
writing dependency_links to pycocotools.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
writing requirements to pycocotools.egg-info\requires.txt
writing top-level names to pycocotools.egg-info\top_level.txt
writing manifest file 'pycocotools.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest file 'pycocotools.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
writing manifest file 'pycocotools.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
installing library code to build\bdist.win-amd64\egg
running install_lib
running build_py
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pycocotools
copying pycocotools\coco.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pycocotools
copying pycocotools\cocoeval.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pycocotools
copying pycocotools\mask.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pycocotools
copying pycocotools\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pycocotools
running build_ext
skipping 'pycocotools\_mask.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
building 'pycocotools._mask' extension
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Python37\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -I../common -IC:\Python37\include -IC:\Python37\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt" /Tc../common/maskApi.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\../common/maskApi.obj -Wno-cpp -Wno-unused-function -std=c99
cl : Command line error D8021 : invalid numeric argument '/Wno-cpp'
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.24.28314\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
```

I have everything up to date, Any help is appreciated thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

```
pip install argparse
pip install dill
pip install fire
pip install matplotlib
pip install numba
pip install psutil
pip install requests
pip install scikit-image
pip install scipy
pip install slidingwindow
pip install tqdm
pip install "git+https://github.com/ppwwyyxx/tensorpack.git"
pip install "git+https://github.com/philferriere/cocoapi.git#egg=pycocotools&subdirectory=PythonAPI"
```

this helped me however not sure about all this packages needs.

couldn't found link where i found it to post here :(

It's not my own investigate, but it's works for me.